# Solution for Poisson equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, poissons-equation

I was assigned to do the following problem and have been stuck with not many ideas.

It is a classical result that if $f\in C^2_{c}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ then the following functions give a solution of the Poisson equaion $-\Delta u=f$,

$$u(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \Phi(x-y)f(y)\,\,\text{d} y.,$$
where $\Phi(x)$ is the fundamental solution of Laplace's equation.

The problem I have to solve is the following:

Given a function $f\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (not necessarily with compact support) that satisfies $|f(x)|\leq \frac{C}{|x|^{\gamma}}$ and $|Df(x)|\leq \frac{C}{|x|^{\gamma+1}}$ for $\gamma$ a positive number. Find conditions on $\gamma$ so that the above defined function $u(x)$ still solves the Poincare equation.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a $\nabla$ in the second inequality?

Comment: yes! just fixed it, thanks.